# Can I specify where I want save the android play asset delivery install-time asset when building the app?

Tags: android

Can I specify where I want save the android play asset delivery install-time asset when building the app? is there any code I can add the following lines to your app's build.gradle file to make that happen?

some thing like:

```
 android {
 ...
 assetPacks {
 // The name of the asset pack.
 name = "my_asset_pack"

 // The directory where the asset pack will be saved.

}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Here is an example -

```
android {
    // ...

    bundle {
        assetPacks {
            pack1 {
                prefer = true
                path = 'pack1_assets'
            }
            pack2 {
                prefer = false
                path = 'pack2_assets'
            }
            pack3 {
                prefer = false
                path = 'pack3_assets'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, you can add single or multiple packs in different locations, prefer will determine which one will be processed first.